# RESTful web service tutorials for .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

Can anyone please suggest a step by step tutorial for RESTful Web services in .NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few (hopefully) useful links:

- MSDN: WCF Web HTTP Programming Model, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx
- MSDN: WCF/Web Samples, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd699772.aspx
- MSDN Magazine Jan 2009, An Introduction to RESTful Services with WCF (is pre-.Net4 but still very readable), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx
- A blog post focussing on the new REST features in WCF 4 and how to use them, http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/drop-the-soap-wcf-rest-and-pretty-uris-in-net-4

Comment: @Web Just be aware that all of that stuff is being made obsolete by the newer Web API stack http://wcf.codeplex.com